# Отпадает MySQL, InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11

Tags: mysql

Иногда падает MySQL сервер, на сайте это проявляется ошибкой, которая гласит, мол, не находит mysqld.sock, собственно на сервере он тоже не создается. В логах выводится ошибка "InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11", лечится перезапуском MySQL, или же убийством процесса и запуском. Подскажите, что может приводить к этой ошибке, и как с этим можно бороться, происходит это в хаотическом порядке, спасибо.

Comment: https://nagg.ru/2012/08/innodb-unable-to-lock-ibdata1-error-11/

Comment: _что может приводить к этой ошибке_ 

Вариант 1 - была попытка запустить вторую копию Mysqld;
Вариант 2 - процесс достиг предела разрешённого количества открытых файлов или блокировок.